# How to replace string with abc\\efg[255 with abc\\efg[23 using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file and it has lines starting with `abc`. 
How can I replace the string `abc\\efg[255` with `abc\\efg[28` using `sed`?

Comment: `sed '/^abc/s/55/8/'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what you've tried so I don't know what part is giving your trouble. Presumably, the issue is that you find that `sed` is choking on your `\`s and `[`. Such special characters need to be escaped by adding a `\` before them. So, to get a literal `\`, you need to write `\\` (and use *single* quotes).

This should work:

```
sed 's/^abc\\\\efg\[255/abc\\\\efg\[28/' file
```

As should

```
sed 's/^\(abc\\\\efg\[2\)55/\128/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r -i 's/^abc\\{2}efg\[255/abc\\\\efg\[28/' file
```

-i argument makes the actual changes to the file

Answer (score -1):

```
printf '%s\n' 'abc\\efg[255' | sed '/^abc/s/55/8/'
```

outputs

```
abc\\efg[28
```

Comment: There are 2 \ present in the string

Comment: `echo "abc\\\\efg[255" |sed '/^abc/s/55/8/'` backslash in input have no more special meaning than a or 2.